# Finding a paper of F. Bogomolov

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Recently I am interested in Bogomolov's Open Image Theorem which is proven in his paper [Sur l'algébricité des représentations l-adiques.](https://scholar.google.ru/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=ru&user=_kTMRyoAAAAJ&citation_for_view=_kTMRyoAAAAJ:t6usbXjVLHcC)

I have tried to find this paper, but it seems that it is not available online. So I wonder whether any of you have a version of this paper.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried on the [Académie des Sciences](https://www.academie-sciences.fr/fr/Transmettre-les-connaissances/comptes-rendus-de-l-academie-des-sciences-numerisees-sur-le-site-de-la-bibliotheque-nationale-de-france.html) webpage?

Comment: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5490641f/f37.item
Is that it?

Comment: @Anthony Saint-Criq: yes and this webpage does not have this paper.

Comment: @Zhevelt: yes, that's great. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good job @Zhevelt. So it *was* on the webpage I linked afterall!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the document of April 21st 1980

https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5490641f/f1.image.zoom#

It contains the article you're looking for.
There is a download button on the right side of the web page.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Now I have an additional webpage to find papers. Thank you!